how to include an image in the build of a multi block plugin
My WP plugin should show some (default) images in the font-end and editor UI. However, the URL generated with my code, refers to the build folder, while the images are not.
This is my structure:

lucy-recipe-blocks
-build
-src
--images
---meal-type-dinner.png
--blocks
---lucy-meal-type-block
----block.json
----edit.js
----index.js
----render.php
----save.js
-webpack.config.js
-lucy-recipe-blocks.php
-package.json

This is the code in render.php:
<?php
  // $image_url = esc_url('/wp-content/plugins/lucy-recipe-blocks/src/images/meal-type-dinner.jpg');
  $image_url = esc_url(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'images/meal-type-dinner.jpg');
  $alt_text = esc_attr('Meal type image');
  $category_title = esc_html('Meal Type Name');
?>

<button class="lucy-meal-type">
  <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" class="lucy-meal-type__image">
  <div class="lucy-meal-type__namespace">
    <label class="lucy-meal-type__text"><?php echo $category_title; ?></label>
  </div>
</button>

This is the webpack.config.js content:
const path = require('path');
const defaultConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(defaultConfig, {
  entry: {
    'lucy-meal-type-block': './src/blocks/lucy-meal-type-block/index.js',
    // Add more blocks as needed
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/blocks'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'images/',
              publicPath: '../images/',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});

Registratie in lucy-recipe-blocks:
function register_lucy_recipe_blocks() {
  $custom_blocks = array(
    'lucy-meal-type-block',
    'lucy-rating-block',
    'lucy-review-card-block'
  );

  foreach ($custom_blocks as $block) {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/' . $block );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_lucy_recipe_blocks' );

package.json:
{
    "name": "lucy-recipe-blocks",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "A WordPress plugin that provides custom recipe blocks for creating and displaying recipes in posts and pages.",
    "author": "The WordPress Contributors",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "main": "build/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build --webpack-copy-php --config webpack.config.js",
        "format": "wp-scripts format",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
        "plugin-zip": "wp-scripts plugin-zip",
        "start": "wp-scripts start --webpack-copy-php --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@wordpress/i18n": "^3.0.0",
        "@wordpress/blocks": "^12.0.0",
        "@wordpress/block-editor": "^12.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.26.0",
        "@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "^8.10.0",
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^30.3.0",
        "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
        "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "sass-loader": "^16.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.95.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ]
    }
}

But the build gives no errors anymore, but I do not have the desired result. lucy-mealtype-block css files are in the build folder and the lucy-mealtype-block folder as well instead of in the blocks folder. And I still do not have the images folder in the build:

When using a static URL (commented out in the code shown) and I remove the webpack.config.js, it works. When I manually copy the image and folder to the build, it works with the dynamic link code. But that is obviously not desired.
I know I`m missing something obvious here....but what? Does it have to do with the fact I'm working with a multi block plugin setup? I would really appreciate feedback.

What are the errors that Webpack gives please?

Hi @Wongjn , I've added the cli errors to the body. If anything else, please let me know. Looking forward!

Still struggling with this. Support would really be appreciated :)

You have a syntax error in your webpack.config.js, it should be module.exports, not module. Exports.

@Wongjn , sorry for the late response. I was working on other parts of the project. Thanks for catching the syntax error - I feel like an idiot :)
But I'm still having issues. I updated the body to reeflect current status. Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

You'd want to merge your webpack config with the config that ships with @wordpress/scripts.

@Wongjn thanks again. I changed the webpack.config (see body). Good news: no more errors. But not the desired result. Still no images in the build and the lucy-mealtype-block build folder is not anymore in the build\blocks folder (see screenprint in the body). Any ideas?

The images aren't include in Webpack's module graph, hence they don't get copied into build. You could consider using something like CopyWebpackPlugin to copy them over.
